# Count the number of arrays in json with a MySQL select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I count the number of arrays in json with a MySQL select statement?

For example, in the following case, I want 2 to be returned.

```
sample
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| id | json                                                |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------------+
| 1  | { items: [{name: a, age: 20}, {name: b, age: 30}] } |
...
```

I was able to get the contents with json_extract.

but I want count the number.

```
select
  json_extract(json, '$.items')
from
  sample
where
  id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_LENGTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-length) function, which is compatible with MySQL 5.7:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$.items'),
       JSON_LENGTH(json, '$.items')
FROM sample 
WHERE id = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b6vUXb89oQASg3YwCjqVkd/0).

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  json_array_length(json_extract(json, '$.items')) as size
from
  sample
where
  id = 1
```

`json_array_length()` is use to count size of json array

Comment: It became an error.

```
#1305 - FUNCTION json_array_length does not exist
```

MySQL version is 5.7.xx, is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick to count, you can use a combination of `LENGTH()` and `REPLACE()` functions.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6725688e72ef6e0fa990fcde76b49eec)

```
SELECT id, json, ROUND((LENGTH(json)- LENGTH(REPLACE(json, 'name', '')))/4,0) AS array_count
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id, '{ items: [{name: a, age: 20}, {name: b, age: 30}] }' AS json
) tmp
```